# Folder icons showing up like files

Tags: directory

[image: Icons of folders looking like files.]

Hi. I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

The icons of MOST folders on my drive and desktop are showing like never-before-seen "file" icons. I can click on them and they'll open, and inside any of the folders, the folder icons are the usual ones: the same orange Linux folder icons.

---

### Additional Clarification

For clarification, I removed some applications from my system in the earlier session, which included an application that can change the "folder color." I had changed the folder color of "Japanaddicts" folder to pink, rest all were usual.

Please tell me how to fix this problem. In that application, there was no such disclaimer that something like this can happen.

Comment: Which application was that? It seems like the main suspect here..

Comment: It seems as you have messed with something in etc or with root folder what do you get when you see the properties of these folders??

Comment: The application was "folder-color (0.0.11)" (Ubuntu Software Centre log).
And what do you mean by proportions? If I open them, everything is intact and no folders show up like icons there (because I never changed the color of any icon besides the folders in the main drive and desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old question but there are no answers.

The solution for me, on Ubunutu 14.04, all I had to do was go into the unity tweak tool and change the icons to default.